# null-conditional operator for date type?

Tags: c#

In my model, I have this property

```
public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Then, in my Blazor razor page, I have the below code which has syntax error

```
<td>@movie.ReleaseDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
```

The issue is because ReleaseDate is nullable but my question is how do I use null-conditional operator `?` to get the system current date if ReleaseDate is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error because a nullable DateTime? doesn't have a `ToString()` overload that takes a string format parameter, so you need to get the `.Value` out of the nullable to turn the nullable into a normal DateTime before you can format it

To answer your specific question about null conditional, this would then something like:

```
(movie.ReleaseDate.HasValue ? movie.ReleaseDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "Not Yet"
```

Alsein's form using null coalesce is a lot more readable than using null conditional but his choice to say a movie was released today if it's release date is null doesn't make sense to me. I'd say we need a way of turning it into a date string only if has a value and turning it into some other string if it is null.

Consider:

```
movie.ReleaseDate?.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") ?? "Not Yet"
```

If release date is null `ToString` won't be called, and c# will skip straight to the `??` with a null result. `??` will then turn the null into a string of "Not Yet", which is what I presume a null release date might mean..

The `?` also works some magic with the nullable, turning it into a `DateTime` if it *does* have a value, which is why the earlier "`DateTime?` doesn't have a `ToString(string)`" doesn't apply; by the time `movie.ReleaseDate?` has been evaluated, the result is either a null or a normal DateTime with a ToString that takes a format

`??` is thus a good way to give a default value to a chain of calls, any one of which might be null and are protected from throwing null reference by many uses of `?` operator:

```
notnull.MaybeNull?.MayAlsoBeNull?.Something ?? DefaultThing
```

Also consider whether you should be formatting the date for the user using this fixed way, or whether it would make more sense to use their culture's typical date format and present the date in different formats to different site visitors

[See something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414123/get-cultureinfo-from-current-visitor-and-setting-resources-based-on-that) or [perhaps this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736406/how-to-modify-the-current-culture-date-format-in-blazor-server) for how to make your code use the user's language declaration to provide culture specific formatting for things like dates and numbers

Comment: Thanks. But when I run the code in Blazor razor page, it shows `02-May-2020 ?? "Not Yet"`

Comment: You probably need to put brackets around the whole thing after the @ because the `?? "not Yet"` is being assumed to be part of the HTML markup not the code. You can tell by the color highlighting what is code and what is html. Like `@( x?.Y() ?? "z" )` - the brackets help c# work out what is code and what is page

Answer (score 3):

`a ?? b` (null-coalescing operator) is a short of `a == null ? a : b`, which means if `a` is `null`, then b is returned, otherwise a.

This operator requires that `a` is of type `T?` (both `Nullable<T>` (aka. nullable value types) and nullable reference types are accepted) and `b` is of type `T` or `T?`. If b is of type `T?`, the return type of this operator is also `T?`, which means `??` could be chained.

`a ?? b ?? c ?? d` means that whichever is not null first is returned.

```
(movie.ReleaseDate ?? DateTime.Now).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_.   Even if the code is a one-liner

Comment: @MickeyD yeah the only person allowed to get away with code only answers hundreds of times a day is Gordon Linoff 

Comment: When I tried this code, the output is `2/5/2020 12:00:00 AM.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")`