# How to blazor inject Globalization.CultureInfo("th-TH")

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Hi i want to call datetime Thai cultureinfo at anywhere and i think should add its scoped or singleton in startup.cs. But i don't know how to do that right.

I would like to inject its to be global var in blazor

```
Globalization.CultureInfo _cultureTHInfo = new Globalization.CultureInfo("th-TH");
```

I want work in other page just call now it will be Thai format.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") = // 02-11-2564
```

Comment: Just check these docs. They explain the ways to do it for web assembly or server blazor.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server

Comment: I think your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133286/12285843

Comment: @Frank that docs link isnt for Blazor.

Comment: @Lotok Deleted reference thanks.