# Cultureinfo Input

Tags: c#, blazor, cultureinfo

I currently run into an issue in my Blazor application, where the users with German system language (Samsung) can't type in decimal numbers. It gets removed instantly. But with English system language, this works perfectly. My guess is, it has to do with the decimal separator since in English it's a dot and in German it's a comma ",".

This is my code for the input component if you want to try out yourself:

```
@using System.Globalization;

<input type="number"
       class="@CssClass"
       value="@CurrentValueAsString"
       id="@Id"
       step="any"
       disabled="@Disabled"
       @oninput="OnChange"/>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string CssClass { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public double CurrentValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public bool Disabled  { get; set; }

    private string CurrentValueAsString;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<double> CurrentValueChanged { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        CurrentValueAsString = CurrentValue.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    private async void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the value
        CurrentValueAsString = (string)e.Value;

        if (double.TryParse(CurrentValueAsString, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var value))
            await UpdateCurrentValue(value);
    }

    async Task UpdateCurrentValue(double newValue)
    {
        CurrentValue = newValue;
        await CurrentValueChanged.InvokeAsync(CurrentValue);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

And this is the call:

```
<InputNumberOnInput CssClass="input-text nomargin"
                    Id="hourPrice"
                    @bind-CurrentValue="VM.Stundenpreis" />
```

Comment: If they input dot as the decimal separator, does it work? You have set the culture in the double.TryParse to InvariantCulture, which means it will only accept dot as the separator.

Comment: @Magnetron On a Samsung Device, it only pops up a number keyboard where dot is the only separator you can click. The comma is disabled. Even pressing on the dot removes the whole input. This behavior is only in German, where the comma is used to seperate decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the user interface culture to German, However, with this part of the code(shown below), you leave the entire culture of the text box unchanged.

```
CurrentValue.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

*Thread.Current**UI**Culture* is intended to be used for User Interface, it's the language used to display text, orientation and so on.
*Thread.CurrentCulture* is intended to be used for parsing/formatting stuffs. Date and time, numbers and string comparison (for example).

If you'd like to change only UI language (and to keep everything else with the culture of your web server) you have to modify only Thread.Current**UI**Culture.

Try below code for parsing the decimal values as per culture.

```
string temp = "10,4";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
double res = double.Parse(temp, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
```

it gives result res = 10.4

You can change `Thread.CurrentUICulture` at the level of a component or apply it globally in `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` as describe in these links: [^](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server), [^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133286/4444757)